# how to set tag to fragments in array list?

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I set up tag to  fragments that are added to a Array list ?
For example

```
public class MainActivity extends Appcompatactivity {

public List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

So, OnCreate I am adding the fragmetns to the list , Here MyFragment is the single fragment I am using

```
fragmentList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("First Fragment")
fragmentList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("second Fragment")
fragmentList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Third Fragment")
fragmentList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fourth Fragment")
```

Here, how can I add a tag to the fragment such that I can delete or add fragment by referring to the Tag set ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map` instead of a `List` . With a `Map` you can save as key value structure.

```
Map<String, Fragment> fragments = new HashMap<>();

fragments.put("First Fragment", MyFragment.newInstance("First Fragment");
```

Afterwards you're able to use the tag as key for `fragments`.

```
fragments.get("First Fragment");
```

Consider using `FragmentManager`respectively `SupportFragmentManager` if you want to control fragments added to your activity. Further reading in the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Managing).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Model class for this.

```
private class FragmentList
{
String tag;
Fragment fragment;
public String getTag() {
return tag;
}

public String setTag(String tag) {
this.tag=tag;
}

public String getFragment() {
return fragment;
}

public String setFragment(Fragment tag) {
this.tag=tag;
}

}
```

and change it-

```
public List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
```

to-

```
public List<FragmentList> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
```

will work for your :)

Comment: Where ever you are adding fragment to fragmentList just set the tag for the same using FragmentList fl= new FragmentList(); fl.setFragment(new Fragment()); fl.setTag("First Fragment");  then add it to list fragmentList.add(fl);